# Why does Update Progress does not fire when AssociatedUpdatePanelId is set?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

When I assign the AssociatedUpdatePanelId, the progress does not display when I select a state, but when I leave it blank, it displays the progress.

Here is the aspx markup:

```
<div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstStates" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="lstStates_SelectedIndexChanged" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    </asp:ListBox>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCounty" runat="server">
    <asp:ListBox ID="lstCounties" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    </asp:ListBox>
    </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lstStates" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" runat="server" DisplayAfter="1"
                        AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
    <img src="../images/loader2.gif" />
    Loading Counties...
    </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETAJAX/125_Using_UpdateProgress_Control_Effectively.aspx), external triggers for an UpdatePanel do not fire an associated UpdateProgress, since the implementation of enabling the UpdateProgress control searches the control hierarchy for the calling control; an external trigger will not be present in the control hierarchy.

The article does, however, suggest injecting some JavaScript to make up for this error; I have modified it to (hopefully) fit your needs:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">
    function pageLoad()
    {      
       var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
       manager.add_endRequest(endRequest);
       manager.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
    }
    function OnBeginRequest(sender, args)
    {
      var postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
      if (postBackElement.id == 'lstStates')
      { 
     $get('UpdateProgress2').style.display = "block";  
      }
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget instead of

```
$get('UpdateProgress2').style.display = "block";
```

to use

```
$get('<%=UpdateProgress2.ClientID%>').style.display = "block";
```

as .NET makes up its own name for the controller (actually appends "MainContent" or whatever to it).