# UpdateProgress not showing when doPostBack is manually called from javascript

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, dopostback, updatepanel-progressbar

I am using update panel and update progress control. In update panel I have textbox with TextChange event. This event is automatically called from javascript when user enters 10 digits into textbox. The call is :

```
__doPostBack("LabelTextBoxCode", "TextChanged");
```

This is my html code :

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                ...processing
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:TextBox ID="LabelTextBoxCode" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextChanged_TextBoxCode">
                        </asp:TextBox>
    ...
  </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So far what I found is this thread [UpdateProgress Not working when called thru javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889099/updateprogress-not-working-when-called-thru-javascript) but it does not help me (I do not know how to use it right in my case).

When I press any button in update panel, progress bar is showing, problem is just with this manually called __doPostBack from javascript.

How to fix it and make updateProgress works ?

Comment: you can find a solution to your problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/996957/why-does-update-progress-does-not-fire-when-associatedupdatepanelid-is-set

Comment: OnBeginRequest is not called when I use __doPostBack

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386518(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly calling __doPostback bypasses all the triggers that set the update panel in action. So to avoid that you can either call the `OnBeginRequest` handler or you can trigger the same button click instead of calling the `__dopostback`. To trigger button click you can make use of jquery trigger function. You can get an example [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I solved it using button (with display:none) and then instead of calling __doPostBack I trigger this button click. It is not perfect solution, but i works. Thanks